# Erro a fazer update a uma tabela. (Duplicate key)

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-update

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Boas. Ao fazer o update da-me erro.. Sim ja la tenho um registo na tabela com aqueles valores, mas ao mudar o tipo não me deveria deixar fazer?

Comment: Qual é a chave primária?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Sim ja la tenho um registo na tabela com aqueles valores, mas ao mudar
>   o tipo não me deveria deixar fazer?

Não, o que você tem que fazer é usar um `Where` , ou seja.

```
Update Falta_Licao
set Tipo = 1,
Descricao = ''
where Id_Turma = 1
and Id_Disciplina 1
and Licao = 1
and Id_Aluno = 3;
```

Praticamente sua tabela tem os dois campos que você pode mudar sem tem nenhum problema, mesmo sem especificar o Where que são o Tipo e a descricao, mas se você tenta fazer um update alterando as chaves primarias da sua tabela pode ser que já tenha um registro com as chaves que você esta informando,.

Veja que a chave primaria da sua tabela é composta por 4 campos, se a combinação desses campo já existir você vai ter esse erro.

Se você precisar fazer update nesses campo o ideal é você ter uma chave unica para tabela, ou seja, criar um Id_Falta_Licao como chave primaria, assim você poderia alterar qualquer campo sem problema.